# Photograph credits in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

Is there any convenient package/way to link photograph credits with a figure, and then generate a kind of `\listoffigures`?

Have you any other solution than generating the `.lof` temporary file, and edit it manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For my thesis I made a "copyright permissions" section, using a combination of `bibunits`, `bibentry` and `cleveref`. I made a bibliography style file that displays the `copyright` field (only for this list--the main bibliography can use a normal style). You can [see the sources](http://www.levbishop.com/thesis/source) for all the details, but in the end, you enter a list like:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item \Cref{fig:coupling,fig:capnet} reproduced with permission from:\\*
    \bibentry{koch_charge-insensitive_2007}.
 \item \Cref{sample,schematic,fig:vrabimap,fig:extjc,fig:exp,fig:relim,%
    fig:hetvsphtcnt,fig:arrows,%
    fig:linecuts,fig:powsweep,fig:hirelim3,fig:wolverine} 
     reproduced (with altered formatting) with permission from:\\*          
     \bibentry{bishop_nonlinear_2009}.
\end{itemize}
```

and this produces a list like:

> • Figures 2.7 and 2.8 reproduced with
>   permission from:
>
> Jens Koch, Terri M. Yu, Jay Gambetta,
>   A. A. Houck, D. I. Schuster, J. Majer,
>   Alexandre Blais, M. H. Devoret, S.
>   M. Girvin, and R. J. Schoelkopf,
>   Physical Review A 76, 042319 (2007).
>
> Copyright (2007) by the American
>   Physical Society.
>
> • Figures 4.2 to 4.8 and 4.10 to 4.14
>   reproduced (with altered formatting)
>   with permission from:
>
> Lev S. Bishop, J. M. Chow, Jens Koch,
>   A. A. Houck, M. H. Devoret, E.
>   Thuneberg, S. M. Girvin, and R. J.
>   Schoelkopf, Nature Physics 5, 105–109
>   (2009).
>
> Copyright © 2009, Nature Publishing
>   Group.

Answer (score 4):

**Attempt #1:** Use `tocloft`

With the [tocloft](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package you can create your own *List of ...* list. [Here](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/) is a nice tutorial. You can define a `\PictureAuthor{John Doe}` command to issue in each figure caption.
However, in the lists of figures there will be no links to the authors (as they will be lested in a separate page).

**Attempt #2":** Use `bibtopic`

You can use the [bibtopic](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibtopic/) package to generate a reference list only for the authors, and use the `cite{John Doe}` command in each picture caption.
Using the `backref` option of the `hyperref` package, in the list of references (generated by `\bibliography{}`), for each of the referenced authors a list of the picture will be appended.

Comment: `tocloft` sounds nice, but I've got a very strange bug which make my \lisfof... always undefined, although I'm sure of my code ... certainly a package conflic ...

Comment: for `bibtopic`, I don't feel really confident using it, because the bibliography is a every complicated topic in this thesis (history of art), so I don't want risk messing everything up!

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't previously attempted exactly what you need (I'm in economics so have little need for photos), I have done something very similar using the ever-powerful but sometimes daunting `glossaries` package.

You can set up any number of *List of...* structures in your doc with `glossaries`, the two standards being *Glossary* and *Abbreviations*. The *List of...* structures can be formatted in a number of canned and tailored ways, including, for example, look-alike of Lev's example in his answer.  If you were to attach the glossary citations (in your case, references to credits) to your figure captions or labels, then only those credits attached to figures actually appearing in your end document would be listed in your *List of Credits*.

For myself, I'm a great fan of the `glossaries` package. It's still relatively new, but that shouldn't stop it from being more widely known.  I have no doubt that it would satisfy your needs.  Nevertheless, it does have a bit of a learning curve, so in that respect it mightn't be as "convenient" as you might like.