# List of figures with sources

Tags: bibliographies, table-of-contents, captions, citing

What is the best way to place the source of images in my document? I have some images and they are shown in the `\listoffigures` like expected, but how can/should I point out where they come from? Should I just add the source to the bibliography and just use the `\cite{...}` in the `\caption` of my figure?

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2527/627) where I gave an answer showing how I dealt with this for my thesis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In academic publications it is common to cite the source of the figure in the caption, mostly at the end of it. You need to put it in the bibliography anyway as soon you use it for 
your work.

Comment: ok, thats what I do at the moment, was just wondering if I need to change that

Comment: You should also check with your supervisor and the style required for your paper or thesis.

Answer (score 6):

To display the source of images less obtrusive than the proper caption, use the [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/floatrow.html) package and its `\floatfoot` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\floatfoot{Source: (Citation command)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```