# Photo credit line

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, tocloft

How do I create a list at the end of a book that looks like this:

[page number][author's name]

Desired output:

Photo credit

[1,3] Author 1, [2] Author 2

Related questions:

[Photograph credits in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2527/photograph-credits-in-latex)
[Figure credit posted inside figure environment, printed in listoffigurecredits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474006/figure-credit-posted-inside-figure-environment-printed-in-listoffigurecredits)

Failed attempt below:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\listexamplename}{Photo Credit}
\newlistof{example}{exp}{\listexamplename}
\newcommand{\credit}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{example}
%\par\noindent\textbf{Example \theexample. #1}
\addcontentsline{exp}{example}
{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\theexample}#1}}

\begin{document}

\listofexample

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \credit{Author 1}
    \label{fig:pic1}
    \end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{Picture 2}
    \credit{Author 2}
    \label{fig:pic2}
    \end{figure}
\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    \caption{Picture 3}
    \credit{Author 1}
    \label{fig:pic3}
    \end{figure}

\section{Photo credits}
(Desired output, created by hand. The page number is in square brackets. The author's data are taken from "credit" field ):

[1,3] Author 1, [2] Author 2.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicates? [Photograph credits in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/2527), [Figure credit posted inside figure environment, printed in listoffigurecredits](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/474006).

Comment: I don't understand the typeset output you are looking for. Thank you for providing an MWE. I would have found it helpful if you had also provide an example of what you hoped your MWE would provide for the entries in the Photo Credit list.

Comment: Are the authors sorted or presented in the order of the appearance of their photographs?

Comment: My gut instinct is that something based on glossaries or indices is the way to go on this.